# Mockk: always calls the real method

Tags: android, kotlin, mockk

I'm trying to mock the return of the following function with mockk, but that always calls the real method. what am I doing wrong?

Below are examples of how I did it:

MakeCall.kt file and no class declarated with kotlin:

```
@File:JvmName("MakeCall")
package com.foo

fun <T> makeCall(call : () -> T) : Single<T> {
    return anyFunction(call)
}
```

ViewModelFile.kt

```
class ViewModelFile(val repository: Repository) : ViewModel() {
    fun loadData() {
        makeCall { repository.loadData() }.flatMap...
    }
}
```

And in my test class I trying this:

```
mockkStatic("com.foo.MakeCall")
val repository: Repository = mockk()
val viewModel = ViewModel(repository)

@Test
fun makeTest() {
    every ...
    every { makeCall { repository.loadData() } } returns Single.just(listOf<Example>())

    viewModel.loadData().test()...
}
```